# How does one stop a key from being held down in C

Tags: c, winapi

I can't seem to figure out how to prevent a key from being held when using the `GetKeyState` function in C. Would anyone be able to know how to do this?

Comment: How do you imagine a C program could cause a human to lift their finger from the key?

Comment: there's no `GetKeyState` in C. It's a Win32 API function

Comment: @Eric Generating an electric shock, maybe? Not sure that such is incorporated (yet) into the Standard Library, though.

Comment: @AdrianMole technically the C standard allows that to happen through undefined behavior ;)

Answer (score 1):

You would use [SetKeyboardState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setkeyboardstate) in junction with [GetKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate) and flip the high order bit of the key to 0 instead of 1. According to MSDN

> The return value specifies the status of the specified virtual key, as follows:
> If the high-order bit is 1, the key is down; otherwise, it is up.

Note this is not standard C but part of the Win32 API.